# C# - Selenium Fails to Retrieve SessionId from WebDriver Service

Tags: c#, selenium

**My Question**

Simple: What am I doing wrong, if anything? If I'm doing everything right, then what can I do to get my tests running again?

**Back-story**

I'm trying to revive an old Selenium project of mine that hasn't been worked on in ~2 years, and I can't even get the simplest of tests to run. In debugging, it seems to be that the session ID isn't being persisted to the Selenium WebDriver, and as such it fails to make all subsequent requests.

The exception I'm currently getting is as follows:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:64334/session//url. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: An error occurred while sending the request. A connection with the server could not be established
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
   at MySeleniumProject.Pages.LoginPage..ctor(IWebDriver driver, IConfiguration config) in C:\TeamFS\Project\Dev\MySeleniumProject\MySeleniumProject\Pages\LoginPage.cs:line 12
   at MySeleniumProject.LoginTests.Can_Log_In_Successfully() in C:\TeamFS\Project\Dev\MySeleniumProject\MySeleniumProject\LoginTests.cs:line 16

Inner Exception 1:
WebException: An error occurred while sending the request. A connection with the server could not be established

Inner Exception 2:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 3:
WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established
```

At the same time, I am able to open Postman and call the driver directly, as seen below:
[image: Postman API call to ChromeDriver.exe]

**Code**

C# .NET Core 2.0

Selenium.WebDriver (3.141.0)

xunit (2.4.1)

chromedriver.exe (76.0.3809.126)

Chrome (76.0.3809.100)

```
protected TestBase()
{
    try
    {
        Config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        Username = Config["Credentials:user"];
        Password = Config["Credentials:password"];

        Driver = CreateDriverFromConfig();
    }
    // This should be a catch. I'm leaving this here so that the question makes sense for future audiences
    finally
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}

private IWebDriver CreateDriverFromConfig()
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    var wd = "WebDriver";
    var selected = Config[$"{wd}:selected"];
    var url = Config[$"{wd}:{selected}:url"] ?? "http://127.0.0.1";

    if (!int.TryParse(Config[$"{wd}:{selected}:port"], out var port))
        port = 26901;
    if (!int.TryParse(Config[$"{wd}:{selected}:timeout"], out var timeout))
        timeout = 10;

    var uri = new Uri($"{url}:{port}");

    Console.WriteLine($"URI: {uri} | Timeout (seconds): {timeout}");

    if (selected.Contains("Edge"))
        driver = CreateEdgeDriver(uri, timeout);
    else if (selected.Contains("Firefox"))
        driver = CreateFirefoxDriver(uri, timeout);
    else if (selected.Contains("Explorer") || selected.Equals("IE"))
        driver = CreateInternetExplorerDriver(uri, timeout);
    else
        driver = CreateChromeDriver(uri, timeout);

    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
    driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1600, 900);

    return driver;
}

private IWebDriver CreateChromeDriver(Uri uri, int timeout)
{
    _cds = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    // _cds.HostName = uri.Host;
    // _cds.Port = uri.Port;
    _cds.Start();

    var co = new ChromeOptions();
    // co.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

    _capabilities = co.ToCapabilities();

    _options = co;
    return new ChromeDriver(_cds, (ChromeOptions) _options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
}

public class LoginTests : TestBase
{
    [Fact]
    public void Can_Log_In_Successfully()
    {
        // arrange

        // act
        var result = new LoginPage(Driver, Config)
            .Login(Username, Password);

        // assert
        Assert.IsType<BlankPage>(result);
    }
}

public class LoginPage : PageBase<LoginPage>
{
    #region Constructor
    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver, IConfiguration config) : base(driver, config)
    {
        Driver
            .Navigate()
            .GoToUrl(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Site_URL") ?? "http://mywebsite.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the service running?  It looks like it is using port 64334.  So you can use cmd.exe >Netstat -a to determine if there is a listener at the port 64334.

Comment: @jdweng No, it wasn't running. The second I posted, I realized I was calling Dispose() via finally in the constructor, and it was killing the process before any actions could be taken. I feel dumb, but thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard the question. I was a dumb-dumb and disposing of my service in the constructor via a try-finally block. Changed it to only run `Dispose()` in the event of an exception, and now it runs.

Thanks anyway. *facepalm*